# Efficient way to query dynamodb table by date

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

How can I make this scenario performant (query dynamodb table)?

I have a table with the following fields:

- id
- reminder_date
- some_metadata_1
- some_metadata_2
- active

I have some part of my code that need to store and access this heavily. It is a table that store future reminders of anything. What could be an efficient way to define keys and indexes?

The regular usage will be: get me all reminders in where date is less than now, that is active.

Currently the table only use id as key, then as I understand, the previous scenario will always require a full scan, so it is going to progressively become slower.

I read something about global secondary indexes, but I didn't grasp fully the concept. Not sure if it makes sense to apply it in this case.

Any help is appreciated.

Update 1:

- The combination reminder_date and active isn't unique.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you’ll want the person as the partition key and the time of the reminder as the sort key. You can query and sort by time, with a filter for the active flag. It depends on the scale you’re dealing with. You can move the flag either into the PK or at the prefix of the SK if you need that constraint to be index-driven.

Comment: Hi there, to clarify, there isn't any person, the id in this table is just a unique value assigned to each item. No semantic on it.

Comment: So how many items in this table, if it’s for basically one person?

Comment: check the regular usage phrase that I mention. 'Get me all reminders in where date is less than now, that is active'. Forget about 'person' isn't mentioned anywhere.  In terms of how many reminders will exists, probably a lot, so to generalize just 'n', big one, that's why I have the concern in the first place. With a low number a scan doesn't hurt, but after some days, this is going to grow heavily.

Comment: The design you want here depends on all your access patterns, and you're only giving one. It's not a typical design to have a single-user reminders database in DynamoDB, so I'm not feeling confident my imagination can fill in the unstated access patterns. Let's just assume you only want to find all items with an attribute X equal to Y and limited by some time range. That design is to make the partition key be X. Make the sort key be the time. Issue a Query where PK=Y and SK<time and you've got exactly what you're looking for. Note: Updating a PK value requires a delete/insert combo.